# What are the career possibilities if I want to live in different countries and learn new languages?

Tags: careers

I wonder if there is such a career, that offers (directly or not) the possibility to live (not just visit) different countries and to learn different languages...

The only one I can think is the Diplomat career, what do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad, to put it mildly, and I'll have to vote to close your question as such. Having said that, I see the world through the eyes of a scholar, a merchant and to an extent, a soldier since I include soldiers and guerrillas in the extended family. And I feel incredibly privileged that I get to see the world through their eyes. Scholars, merchants and soldiers all understand the importance of speaking the language of the people they interact with. And we all appreciate the kindness and hospitality of strangers :)

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped..." ([help/dont-ask])

Comment: Could you suggest any edition to make my question less broad? thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be looking at it from the wrong end. It's not the profession / career which *allows* you to live in different countries, it's you who is making a conscious *choice* about this (and maybe rearranging your life and habits to support it).

If you want to learn languages, just pick your favourite and start learning it today :-) Once you can talk a bit, you can leave for a trip abroad. Or even before. I got a scholarship to Spain during my uni years so I was lucky enough to spend 6 months there. I knew about two words in Spanish when I arrived, with a language coursebook in my pack, and spent many of my evenings studying. By the time I left Spain, I could speak fairly fluently. It was one of the best times of my life!

As the example shows, there are lots of other possibilities apart from getting a proper job abroad, if you want to discover the world:

- Get a scholarship to a school in a foreign country
- Get a regular job at home, save for a while then live out of your savings for a while in a foreign country (it helps if life is significantly cheaper there than in your home country). You don't even need a very fancy job for that -  I met a Swiss plumber in India who used to do that, spending about half of his time in India on average.

But if you want a proper job, you can choose one which is international enough and in demand globally, like

- IT jobs
- translator / language teacher
- social worker, like a nurse caring for elder or mentally / physically challenged people - these are actually in ever higher demand especially in the most developed countries
- health care - demand similar to the above. Localizing the diploma received in your home country may require a tedious process though.

Answer (score 2):

Teaching English in foreign countries like Korea, China, and others would be one example. These can be 9 months or many years in some cases.

Humanitarian workers that work for NGOs in third world countries would also be another example here. For example, I know of people that will be spending years living in parts of Asia or Africa as part of their long-term assignments over there that would likely include learning the culture and language in such places. Mother Theresa would be a bit extreme for an example here.